# Recommendations for Monitoring services

Tags: monitoring, daemon, monit, daemontools, god

I would like to install a monitoring services (Monit or others) on my web server and am looking for recommendation.

I have no idea which is good, and what parameters which I should evaluate on, and which is a good for for my needs.

Some which I saw and am evaluating are

Monit  http://mmonit.com/monit/
God  http://god.rubyforge.com
Daemontools http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html

About my server

Ubuntu/Apache/Nginx/Mysql Serving Django application.

Some other services I need to be monitoring.

Openoffice running headless.
Custom python daemons.
Xvfb.

Parameters which are important are, (in order).

Reliable.
Easy to install and monitor.
Not too resource heavy.
Unixy.
Send email when a service goes down.
Has webpage with status of services.

Which of the above or other tools is best for my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monit satisfies all you requirements. It is easy to install, setup, add services, send emails and has a builtin http server. We've been running monit for over a year now without downtime.

I've not tried the others.

Answer (score 3):

++ for Monit http://mmonit.com/monit/

Answer (score 1):

easy to install = may be you are not going to receive all the info you want.

May be you can install munin, its easy and as a munin-node you'll be able to monitorize mysql,cpu, ram and other stuff. 
http://www.howtoforge.com/server_monitoring_monit_munin
It's very easy to install but it will not send any mail to alert you.
If you would like to receive some mails, you can just install postfix as internetmail and mutt or mailx as mailer. So you can launch cron scripts checking whatever you would like to check, even fix it if its a process eating all the ram, and then send a mail.

On the other hand, nagios+cacti, nagios as monitor and cacti as mail and checkers. It's hard to install and configure on the first time, so may be you can go and check Groundwork, a fork from nagios which is not so free but it can be free as beer. You can try it as an vmware appliance for test purposes. Also if you have money, you can get support and is nagios with stuff on top of it, so it will just work.

Finally if you would like to monitor your apache service at the level of from where and what the people are visiting I will suggest awstats, or google analytics.

All this is based on my experience, so I can be wrong and I'll accept opinions and corrections. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go with nagios or Community version of the following :
- Groundworks
- ZenOs
- Zabbix

If you want to take a look of some comparison you can go to [link text](http://blog.carlosgomez.net/2009/10/nagios-replaced-with-groundworks.html)